# Laravel Validation Error customise format of the Response

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I am working with L5 Form Requests and don't I just love Taylor! Well, I am doing some AJAX requests and I still want to retain my form requests. The problem is that in the case of a validation error the Validator just returns a 422 error response and flashes the errors, but my AJAX frontend expects a very specific format of response from server whether validation is successful or not.

I want to format the response on Validation errors to something like this

```
return json_encode(['Result'=>'ERROR','Message'=>'//i get the errors..no problem//']);
```

My problem is how to format the response for the form requests, especially when this is not global but done on specific form requests.

I have googled and yet not seen very helpful info. Tried this method too after digging into the `Validator` class.

```
// added this function to my Form Request (after rules())
    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    return ['Result'=>'Error'];
}
```

Still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Laravel 5 custom validation redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544779/laravel-5-custom-validation-redirection)

All you need to do is to add a `response()` method in your form request and it will override the default response. In your `response()` you can redirect in whatever fashion you want.

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    // Optionally, send a custom response on authorize failure 
    // (default is to just redirect to initial page with errors)
    // 
    // Can return a response, a view, a redirect, or whatever els
    return response()->json(['Result'=>'ERROR','Message'=>implode('<br/>',array_flatten($errors))]); // i wanted the Message to be a string
}
```

**UPDATE on L5.5+**
This error and the accepted solution was for L5.4. For L5.5, use Ragas' answer above (failedValidation() approach)

Comment: Did you have to do anything else other than what you outlined? I'm trying your solution and while I get a response the json structure is no where near my formatted response... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100798/format-formrequest-validation-error-response

Comment: i did not have to do anything else, and it has worked well ever since. Your case seems to have already been handled since you have accepted the answer there.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, it would be fair enough to suggest what the issue is, and even suggest a better answer.

Comment: Hi. This seems to have stopped working with Laravel 5.4. In 5.5 there is a method called `failedValidation` that should Ideally do the same!

Answer (score 22):

Currently accepted answer no longer works so i am giving an updated answer.

In the revelent `FormRequest` use `failedValidation` function to throw a custom `exception`

```
// add this at the top of your file
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator; 
use App\Exceptions\MyValidationException;

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    throw new MyValidationException($validator);
}
```

Create your custom exception in `app/Exceptions`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class MyValidationException extends Exception {
    protected $validator;

    protected $code = 422;

    public function __construct(Validator $validator) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function render() {
        // return a json with desired format
        return response()->json([
            "error" => "form validation error",
            "message" => $this->validator->errors()->first()
        ], $this->code);
    }
}
```

This is the only way I found. If there is a better approach please leave a comment.

This works in laraval5.5, I don't think this will work in laravel5.4 but i am not sure.

Comment: Have been using the accepted answer (by me :)) in L5.4 and have not tested it in 5.4+, so if the one you have given works, that's fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you are in laravel 5+ you can easily achieve this, by overriding the `invalid()` or `invalidJson()` method in the `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` file

In my case, I was developing an API and the api responses should be in a specific format, so I have added the following in the `Handler.php` file.

```
/**
     * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'code'    => $exception->status,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'errors'  => $this->transformErrors($exception),

        ], $exception->status);
    }

// transform the error messages,
    private function transformErrors(ValidationException $exception)
    {
        $errors = [];

        foreach ($exception->errors() as $field => $message) {
           $errors[] = [
               'field' => $field,
               'message' => $message[0],
           ];
        }

        return $errors;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. Will want to try this one out and see how it works

Comment: Great idea. Works fine!

Answer (score 2):

in `\App\Exceptions\Handler`

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{

    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        //custom response
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "validation error",
            'data' =>$e->errors()
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 422);
    }


    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in laravel 8+ you can do this just in App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
// Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
    $this->renderable(function (ValidationException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => $e->getMessage(),
                'message' => $e->validator->errors(),
            ], 400);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach if you're using Laravel 8+

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired by [this post](https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-api-errors-and-exceptions-how-to-return-responses/) and the answer by Shobi. Why not keep the `transformErrors` function from the Shobi's answer and simply modify the `render` function inside `Handler.php`? An example would look like:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param Exception $exception
 * @return Response
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => $exception->status,
            'error' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'message' => $this->transformErrors($exception)
            ], $exception->status);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

This makes `invalidJson` function redundant and allows to add more fine-grained differentiation of custom json responses on each type of exception.

Tested on Laravel 6.2