# Format FormRequest Validation Error Response

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.3

With reference to this [stack question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097371/laravel-validation-error-customise-format-of-the-response) I'm trying to format the response of my error validations to a more simplified format...thus in a custom App\Http\Requests\CustomRequest I have

```
public function rules()

{
    return [
        'amt' => 'required|numeric|min:1000',
        'year' => 'required|numeric|min:' . date_format(new \DateTime, 'Y'),
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'ratio' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function response(array $errors)
   {
       if ($this->expectsJson()) {
          return response()->json(['messsage'=>'Cannot Validate','errors'=> $errors]);
       }

       return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                       ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                       ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
   }

/**
    * Format the errors from the given Validator instance.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
    * @return array
    */
   protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
   {
       return [];
   }
```

in my controller I have

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response Header 201
     */
    public function store(CustomFormRequest $request)
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();
        Budget::create($requestData);

        return response([], 201);
    }
```

According to the laravel docs I just have to "typehint" the the request. However my response is always.

> {"id":"validation_failed","message":"Validation
>   failed.","meta":{"errors":{"amt":[{"rule":"min.numeric","message":"The
>   amt must be at least 1000.","parameters":["1000"]}]}}}

Which doesn't make sense if I'm changing the response format. What i need is

> {"id":"validation_failed","message":"Validation
>   failed.","errors":[{"amt":{"message":"The
>   amt must be at least 1000."}}]}

I'm not sure what I should be doing at this point. What else is there?

Comment: An ability to override default output was just implemented. So if you still need it, just look in the readme of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side-channel communication (IRC) revealed that Kendall is using [lanin/laravel-api-exceptions](https://github.com/mlanin/laravel-api-exceptions). This package has a custom exception handler that changes Laravel's built-in ValidationException into a custom exception class, and custom output handling. A hint that the output wasn't generated by Laravel can be the `meta` key in the json output, Laravel does not produce that.

The question mentions the `response(array $errors)` and the `formatErrors(Validator $validator)` methods of FormRequest, but these are not used by this package.

The json result of validation failures can be modified by overriding the custom exception handler's `renderForApi` method, check for `ValidationFailedApiException`, and return a custom response for these.

Answer (score -1):

To have a custom error message I suppose you are looking for the `messages` method. On that method, just return an array.

Example: `['fieldName.rule' => 'Custom message']`

See: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_messages

Bonus: if you want to name the field name also just make a `attributes` method.

See: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_attributes

Comment: I'm not really trying to change the text message but more the json object structure.... see updated question