# Laravel 5.5. validation request redirect/response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

Can I override some property in validation request to control what happens if validation fails? (I don't want to use validation in controller)

I have user validation request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique:user',
        'name'                  => 'required',
        'password'              => 'required|min:6',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|same:password'
    ];
}
```

And when AJAX call is made to register method this happens:

```
public function postRegisterAjax(UserRegistrationValidationRequest $request)
{
    ...
    return $this->responseJson($status, $msg);
}
```

I need to update `$msg` somehow so that I can return the validation error message dynamically through JS.

**EDIT: my final solution** (in my custom form request)

```
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $status = Status::ERROR;
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(["response" => [
            'msg'    => $validator->errors()->all(':message'),
            'status' => $status
        ]]));
    }

    return response()->json(["response" => [
        'msg'    => 'User successfully registered',
        'status' => Status::SUCCESS
    ]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To return the validation error message*:

In **Laravel Form Request Validation**, if validation fails, in the case of an AJAX request, a JSON response will be returned. The JSON response holds all validation errors. You can access them in your `ajax` error response.
(dump your error response, you can see them in `responseJSON`).

If you would like to add additional logic/validation and append errors to your `error bag`, you can use [after-validation-hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#after-validation-hook).

Hope it will help you..

**UPDATE**

You can override the `laravel form request`'s response method like the follwing,

```
public function response(array $errors)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => $status, "response" => $errors]);
    }
```

in your response you would be able to access the errors as `data.response`

Comment: Is it possible to modify so that instead of `responseJSON` I get back `response` property?

Comment: if i understand you correct, you can access your desired `response` as `response.responeJSON`.

Comment: I can access it with `data.responseJSON` (the same as what you wrote, depending on what you pass in function argument), but I would like to have `data.response`. I meant if it is possible to change the `responseJSON` to be called `response` instead?

Comment: answer updated. Hope this is what you wanted. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097371/laravel-validation-error-customise-format-of-the-response and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544779/laravel-5-custom-validation-redirection

Comment: Exactly what I needed! `failedValidation()` instead of `response()` in Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
public function postRegisterAjax(UserRegistrationValidationRequest $request)
{
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $msg = $validator->errors();
            return $this->responseJson($status, $msg);
        }
}
```

Comment: That wasn't my question. The messages never get fed to the ajax because the validation fails before I am able to return json response

Comment: And from where do you get that $data and $rules? You mean $request->all() and $this->rules()

Comment: Yeah, that can't work since validator fails before you even enter the function