# Catch the value of an input field that has been rejected by the Validation rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Here is the situation : When I submit a form made with Blade / Laravel Collective, if a field doesn't match the requirements of the validation rules, the input fields of the form are reloaded. I noticed that Laravel is first populating the input fields with the data from the previous loading (like if used "old" function) and, the second time the data entered by the user overwrites the previous data. (I've verified this by setting a js console.log check on the content of the input field which does not pass the validation rules before the file is sent to the browser and once it is loaded into the browser).

Precision : As I use a NOSQL Database, I do not use Eloquent to build the Form so I populate "manually" the input fields of the form with an array containing data from DB (named inputs) like this :

```
{!!  Form::text($field, $inputs[$field], ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

I think that the issue is coming from this way of loading data in the form but I'm not able to explain when and why Laravel loads the contents the second time.

As I need to get the values of the fields rejected by the validation rules for a specific task, I would like to know if there is a Helper or something else that provides the values of the fields that the user has entered before validation.

**EDIT**

Finally, I'm pretty sure that Laravel does not populate the form inputs after validation error(s), the browser does it automatically because Laravel is redirecting back. So, the only way to "catch" the inputed data from the blade template should be to flash it into session vars when Laravel is redirecting but as it is done automatically by the FormRequest class and that the withValidator() function doesn't work when I put it into the class that extends FormRequest(), it seems fairly impossible....

Comment: Catch ?? 
How are u redirecting back if valildation fails?

Comment: Good question. My validation rules are set in the rules() function of a class that extends FormRequest Class and that's all I do on this part, Laravel is doing the rest of the job for redirecting back.

Comment: Share me the controller code where u do if validator->fails()

Comment: Hum, I've just checked in my controller and I've never written a single line containing this instruction. However, Laravel is directing back when the validation rules doesn't pass, the version that I use is 5.3

Comment: share ur controller need to see that

Comment: ok, how can I do this without letting it in comment ? (the file is too long)

Comment: You can edit the question

Comment: did it right now :)

Comment: what is perso repository?? 
Add that file too ..

Comment: It's the core logic of my app and I can't publish it online for two reasons : the code is really big and it extends another class, and more than that I need to keep it private for professional reasons. However, If you tell me exactly what you need to see I can show you specific code parts.

Comment: are u validating there ?? 
i need to see from where are u validating ??

Comment: @Jigs1212 , from the info in the `controller` and  his comment, he is using FormRequest validation is used for the validation. (PersoCreateRequest.php)

Comment: @Riw, you don't have to paste the entire controller or class. Just paste the relevant data which need to give a clear picture of your question.

Comment: @Jigs1212 Yes, I checked all my code and I do not validate anything at any moment. I suppose that FormRequest is managing it automatically.

Comment: ok, so according to the official doc on laravel.com, I can confirm that the data is validated by FormRequest automatically : "If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors."

Comment: I'v edited my post because I arrived to a conclusion, though I still do not have a solution. Thank you @Jigs1212 to try to help me and ab_in too even if you disappeared without saying a word.

Comment: if u know how it is getting redirected u can use ->withInput() in the redirect . That is ` return back()->withInput();` this will bring back ur input.

And usin `$input['fieldname'];` should work for you.

Comment: @Riw From your last comment on my answer made me understand that what I understand from your question was entirely different from what you ask, that why I vote for deleting my answer.

Comment: @Riw Now if I understand your question right then you may use like `{!!  Form::text($field, old('order' , $inputs[$field]), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}`. This takes `old('order')` data if old data is present else it take your `$inputs[$field]`. If it doesn't make sense then refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829595/laravel-5-5-validation-request-redirect-response/47834813#47834813)

Comment: Hi @ab_in, sorry for my late answer. What you propose still doesn't work because $inputs[$field] still refer to what comes from my database...  I sincerely thank you for having tried to help me with interest. Finally, I found a solution to my problem on the front-end side even if it wasn't the goal, what I was looking for is working... Thanks again.